# Query with the same fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to do this query.
I have these three tables
    projects
        id
        name

```
authors
    id
    id_user
    fk_id project
    type = author, editor
```

in Table I have authors who is the creator and who is the editor
I'm trying to make a query in mysql where you can see in one record
who is the author and publisher.

I do the consultation with one of the two

```
SELECT p.id_project,p.name_project,a.fk_id_user,a.type,u.name    
FROM projects p,users u, authors a
where p.id_project = a.fk_id_project 
and a.type = 'author' 
and a.fk_id_user = u.id_user
```

**the result is**

```
   id_project, name_proyect, type, user, name_user
    1 ,         bambo,       author, 145, andrea
```

want is to do this

```
id_project, name_proyect, type, user, name_user, type2, user2, name_user2
1         ,bambo        , author,145, andrea,   editor, 785,    barack
```

try to do this but not worked

```
SELECT p.id_project,p.name_project,a.fk_id_user,a.type,u.name,a.fk_id_user as user2, a.tipo as type2
FROM
projects p, users u, authors to
where p.id_project = a.fk_id_project 
and a.type = 'author' 
and a.fk_id_user = u.id_user 
and user2 = u.id_user 
and Typo2 = 'editor'
```

That type of query could use or if I'm doing wrong this.

Comment: Please elaborate on the phrase, "but not worked".  What actually happened when you ran that query?

Comment: is `projects p, users u, authors to` a typo? if not you need to change `authors to` to `authors a`

Comment: Also, he says Typo2 instead of type2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suggest using LEFT or INNER JOIN authors a ON blablabla instead of having everything in the WHERE clause. However, try this:

```
SELECT
p.id_proyecto,
p.nombre_proyecto,
a.tipo,
a.fkidusario,
u.Nombres,
aa.tipo as type2
aa.fkidusario as user2,    
uu.Nombres as name_user2

FROM proyectos p 
JOIN usuarios u 
JOIN usuarios uu 
LEFT JOIN responsables a ON p.id_proyecto = a.fkidproyecto AND a.tipo = 'author' AND a.fkidusario = u.id_usuario 
LEFT JOIN responsables aa ON  p.id_proyecto = aa.fkidproyecto AND aa.tipo = 'editor' AND aa.fkidusario = uu.id_usuario
```

Comment: +1 to using `LEFT JOIN` vs putting everything in the `WHERE` clause. It's tremendously easier to read.  I think you should update your example to show joins in action.

Comment: Tried, but its hard without the db schema

Comment: thanks for the help, the scheme is this
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71291454/esquema.png 
I did the query so

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71291454/consulta.PNG

and the results were repeated
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71291454/resultado.PNG

Comment: Updated to match schema, try this :)